# What am I doing wrong trying to pass and capture an input text field to a .php file for writing to .txt file? Test Code follows:

Tags: php, forms, variables, capture

My code for testing is as follows:
Both files are .php to avoid conflict, I have been programming for 30 years, but am new to .js and .php, I can't figure out the syntax for what should be an easy effort. I have read and tried all applicable examples but they haven't worked for me. PLEASE TELL ME WHERE I'M SCREWING UP!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>TestofTopicText</title>
    <script language="Javascript">
    <!--
    function OnButton1()
    {
    var newtopic = document.getElementById('topic');
    document.Form1.target = "_self";    
    document.Form1.action = "1-open-close.php?var=$newtopic";
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    }
    -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h3><span style="color: #00ff00;">If NOT found to right ENTER Your Topic Here!        </span></h3>
    // Using get method as I read was appropriate for getElementById
    <form id="Form1" method="get" name="Form1">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="topic" size="55" />
      <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" onclick="OnButton1()"/>
    </form>
    </body>

    </html>

    // I am passing to this .php file known as 1-open-close.php
    // The file opens and writes test text but I can't get topic text from other file?
<?php
    $topic = $_GET['var'];
    $myFile = "Topics.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Test to Make Sure Open \n";
    fwrite($fh, $topic);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    // return true;
?>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are really looking to involve javascript in this, but you could simplify by just using the form behavior native to html, and reference the input passed in.  i.e. You've already specified the form as method GET, so the input type text contained within the form tags will be posted without any extra effort.  On the php side, you can reference that value coming through by using the "name" specified on the html input as the index to the array.  Hope this helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>TestofTopicText</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h3><span style="color: #00ff00;">If NOT found to right ENTER Your Topic Here!        </span></h3>
    // Using get method as I read was appropriate for getElementById
    <form id="Form1" method="get" name="Form1" action="1-open-close.php">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="topic" size="55" />
      <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search"/>
    </form>
    </body>

    </html>

    // I am passing to this .php file known as 1-open-close.php
    // The file opens and writes test text but I can't get topic text from other file?
<?php
    $topic = $_GET['q'];
    $myFile = "Topics.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Test to Make Sure Open \n";
    fwrite($fh, $topic);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    // return true;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with 'q'. I had it coded as I did because my actual application has multiple actions required with different types of methods and actions. Can you explain why or what the difference was in using Name versus Id from input? If I were add an if var!='', would that be proper syntax to make sure var which would be 'q' is not empty?

Comment: In your original code, you were referencing your variable newtopic a little bit incorrectly.  (You were doing what you would do in php by using the dollar sign in front of the variable, and including it within your string)  For the string concatenation in javascript you'd need to do something like: document.Form1.action = "1-open-close.php?var="+newtopic;

Comment: And... in regard to your question about id vs. name.  The only difference is that html forms will use the "name" property natively when it is submitted.  Since you are bypassing that with your javascript, it doesn't really affect it.

Comment: And one other thing... by using an input of type "submit", you might run into issues where the form could submit using native html functionality.  To avoid this, you could change it to a type "button" i.e. <input type="button" name="sa" value="Search" onclick="OnButton1()"/>

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't interpolate variables like PHP does, so it is literally sending the string `$newtopic` instead of what you want. The whole thing is redundant anyway. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>TestofTopicText</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3 style="color:#0f0;">If NOT found to right ENTER your topic here!</h3>
  <form method="post" action="1-open-close.php">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="55" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your PHP file should be:

```
<?php
$topic = $_POST['q'];
$myFile = "Topics.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile,"a") or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Test to make sure open\n";
fwrite($fh,$topic);
fwrite($fh,$stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see you put your form action into your javascript. That's weird. Anyway:

I suggest you use a LOT of echo statements to find out what variables' values are.

Useful things:

```
print_r($_POST); // find out what values have been received by POST method
print_r($_SESSION); // find out what values are stored in SESSION
```

Surround those `print_r` with `<pre></pre>` tags to make them easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var newtopic = document.getElementById('topic');
document.Form1.target = "_self";    
document.Form1.action = "1-open-close.php?var=$newtopic";
```

You are trying to pass the JavaScript variable newtopic with $newtopic (which is the syntax for PHP variables, and does not apply here).
And you are also trying to send the element itself, which does not make sense.
The input box has a name="q" and that is what you should be accessing in PHP.

Nevertheless the code is still badly formed. You will get errors from trying to access "q" before it is sent.

I've added an action to the form, and deleted your script which was not necessary. I've also changed `$topic = $_GET['var']` to `$topic = $_GET['q'];`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>TestofTopicText</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h3><span style="color: #00ff00;">If NOT found to right ENTER Your Topic Here!        </span></h3>
    // Using get method as I read was appropriate for getElementById
    <form id="Form1" method="get" name="Form1" action="1-open-close.php">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="topic" size="55" />
      <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </body>

    </html>

    // I am passing to this .php file known as 1-open-close.php
    // The file opens and writes test text but I can't get topic text from other file?
<?php
    $topic = $_GET['q'];
    $myFile = "Topics.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Test to Make Sure Open \n";
    fwrite($fh, $topic);
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
    // return true;
?>
```

Comment: Ok, always getting late... Benjamin Powers and Kolink gave the solution first.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with 'q'. I had it coded as I did because my actual application has multiple actions required with different types of methods and actions. Can you explain why or what the difference was in using Name versus Id from input? If I were add an if var!='', would that be proper syntax to make sure var which would be 'q' is not empty?

Comment: I think @BenjaminPowers already explained the name vs. id part. Concerning the variable being empty or not, you just need to add an if  to test if the variable is set or not:  if (isset($_GET['q'])) {... open and write to file ...}

Comment: I also advise you to make further tests when opening and writing to files. See http://www.php.net/fopen and http://www.php.net/fwrite